# Syncfusion Calendar Schedule View Set Scroll Position at Start

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I am trying to set the initial scroll position as I have a floating search bar that will sit above my calendar.

Here is what it looks like on load as you can see the initial date is hidden:

[image]

Here is what I want it to look like on start as you can see the initial date is just below my floating search bar:

[image]

Anyone know how I can achieve this? Setting the initial start date 1/2 days behind is not an option as the height will vary based on the number of events in those days.

Answer (score 0):

As per the current implementation of the calendar, there is no support to change the initial scroll position. The calendar will be positioned as the initial date view based on the initial display date value or controller display date value.

Please refer to the following UG link for more information.
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/getting-started#initial-display-date
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/date-navigations#programmatically-change-to-adjacent-dates